# Multiple AuthenticationManagers for http elements

Tags: spring-security

I have read that the solution to having multiple http elements and defining different authentication managers for them is to use ID instead of ALIAS.

I have tried this and many other solutions, please help.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Exclude public pages and static resources -->
    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />

    <http pattern="/test*"  use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="smsAuthManager">            
        <intercept-url pattern="/test" access="hasRole('ROLE_SMS_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/refreshLoginPageTuring" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login login-page="/loginTuring" default-target-url="/test" login-processing-url="/loginTuring" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
        <!-- <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/> -->       
    </http>

    <!-- <beans:bean id="smsAuthManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="com.swivelsecure.userportal.SMSAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean> -->

    <authentication-manager id="smsAuthManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="sMSAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager> 

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="userPortal">
        <intercept-url pattern="/getQRCode" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/refreshLoginPageTuring" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" /> -->

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/menu" login-processing-url="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/errors/error" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/menu" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    </http> 

    <authentication-manager alias="userPortal">
        <authentication-provider ref="userPortalAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'smsAuthManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsAuthManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sMSAuthenticationProvider' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sMSAuthenticationProvider' is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defined in your exception:

> No bean named 'sMSAuthenticationProvider' is defined

To fix it, make sure you define the bean. Based on your example it might look something like this:

```
<beans:bean id="sMSAuthenticationProvider"
            class="com.swivelsecure.userportal.SMSAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Comment: Hi Rob, this I have fixed with @Service but I have a tricky situation that I could do with some direction. I have 2 forms each with there own authProvider. I have set a login-processing-url= but the url is blocked seems the form is auto submitting.

Comment: I never reach the smsAuthProvider why's this